# Calling a GenServer fails due to an incorrect name

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I have this GenServer in a library:

```elixir
defmodule MyLib.Cache do
  use GenServer

  def start_link([]) do

    IO.puts("****cache genserver, name: #{__MODULE__}")


    # GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: __MODULE__)
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: MyLibCache)   # no dot
  end
  # [.........]
```

And this application:

```elixir
    defmodule MyApp.Application do
      use Application

      def start(_type, _args) do
        import Supervisor.Spec

        children = [
          {Phoenix.PubSub, [name: MyApp.PubSub, adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]},
          {MyLib.Repo, []},
          {MyAppWeb.Endpoint, []},
          {MyLib.Cache, []} # notice the dot
        ]
```

- Why is it working work when I specify name: `MyLibCache` (without a dot) although the name must be `MyLib.Cache` - with a dot?
- I want to be able to use `name: __MODULE__` in the GenServer. But with it, it'll fail to start it in `application.ex` because it won't find the module with such a name. How to fix it?

**update**:

error at runtime, **only** when I try to access a page where Cache is called, that is, not at startup:

> `exited in: GenServer.call(MyLibCache, {:get, "Elixir.MyLib.Dal.User.2"}, 5000) ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started`

namely, this will work with no error:

```elixir
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: MyLibCache)
# or 
# GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: MyLib.Cache) # with dot
```

this - with the error shown above:

```elixir
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: __MODULE__)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Supervisor.Spec`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html) has been deprecated since Elixir 1.5. You do not need to use it. Here a working example:

```elixir
defmodule MyLib.Cache do
  use GenServer

  def init(state), do: {:ok, state}

  def start_link(state) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state, name: __MODULE__)
  end
end
```

Then in `application.ex`:

```elixir
def start(_type, _args) do
  children = [
    MyLib.Cache
  ]

  opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
  Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
end
```

> Why is it working work when I specify name: MyLibCache (without a dot) although the name must be MyLib.Cache - with a dot?

The `name` argument to [`GenServer.start_link/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#start_link/3) is the name of the *server*, not the module. They can be the same, but they don't have to be. The name you supply here is the name that needs to be supplied to [`Genserver.call/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#call/3) later. See [Name registration](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration) for details.

Comment: `__MODULE__` in `defmodule MyLib.Cache` will evaluate into `Elixir.MyLib.Cache`, whereas in application.ex you're refering to it as simply `MyLib.Cache`. How can it work?

Comment: In Elixir, module names are just atoms. They all start with `Elixir.`, but this is omitted for brevity. You can test it by doing `IO.puts(MyLib.Cache)`. Also `is_atom(MyLib.Cache)` and `Elixir.MyLib.Cache == MyLib.Cache`.